# Issues in running presto CLI in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, presto, opera-presto

I am running presto on Kubernetes and on running presto CLI.

I am getting the below error.

I had set up Postgres, hive metastore and presto server and all the pods are up and running. Init schema is also done

**Version used:** Presto server 0.234

Hive standalone metastore: 3.0.0

Presto CLI: 0.234

```sh
Error running command: java.net.SocketTimeoutException**
java.io.at com.facebook.presto.client.JsonResponse.execute(IsonResponse.java:154)
at com.facebook.presto.client.StatementclientFactory.newstatementclient(StatementclienFactory.java:24)
at com.facebook.presto.cli.QueryRunner..
.........

**Caused bat sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.comect(SocketAdaptor.java:118)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.** RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:238)
```

Comment: Kubernetes is tricky to configure right. Since this is asking for troubleshooting help, which seems a bit beyond SO scope, you can also try asking on `#troubleshooting` channel on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).

Comment: How did you setup Presto and how are you running your client? from where?

Comment: Got an image of opera presto 0.234 from which setup the presto server , similarly for postgres.simlarly created  image of hive metastore using hive stand alone metastore. And set up the hive metastore ans also did initialize of schema. Use presto cli executable jar to create image ans deployed. Did exec/bash to cli pod and then ran command for to get into presto  cli and then ran query